# Laravel Yajra datatables highcharts integration

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts, laravel-10, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to integrate highcharts with yajra but for now I haven't succeeded, at the moment to display the table in the blade view file I have this code, but how to recognize the table with highcharts is not yet clear to me, I'm trying anyway with negative result I don't see any results, does anyone have any idea how to do this? In the table I have performed some counts and calculations that I would like to see with highcharts and therefore I should be able to recognize the TableDatatables.php table that I display with this code inserted in the view

```
@section('content')
    <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-title">Tickets</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="my-datatable" class="col-md-12">
                                    {{ $dataTable->table() }}
                                </div>
                                <div id="container"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            @include('layout.footer')
        </footer>
    </div>
@endsection
    @push('scripts')
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        {{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var table = $('#my-datatable').find('table');
        var api = $( table ).DataTable();
        const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                styledMode: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Staff Count Per Position'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    data: chartData(table)
                }
            ]
        });
        
        // On each draw, update the data in the chart
        table.on('draw', function () {
            chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table));
        });
        
        function chartData(table) {
            var counts = {};
        
            // Count the number of entries for each position
            table
                .column(1, { search: 'applied' })
                .data()
                .each(function (val) {
                    if (counts[val]) {
                        counts[val] += 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        counts[val] = 1;
                    }
                });
        
            return Object.entries(counts).map((e) => ({
                name: e[0],
                y: e[1]
            }));
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: What does the returned table look like? What is its structure? If this is a problem strictly with Highcharts, it is probably because the transferred data has the wrong format/structure.